# Special symbols in an excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I see a formula excel with symbol "--" before isnumber as below:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&B37&" ", " "&$A$2:$A$502&" ")))>0, TRUE, FALSE)
```

Can you help me what "--" is for? And if possible, can you help to list symbols used in excel formular? For example, as i know, "*" is usually used in formula relating to strings of text.

Just found something new to me and want to learn more about that.

Comment: please open my question. i want to know if there's any other special symbol like that

Answer (score 1):

"--" is not a special operator. It's actually two "-" unary negation operators.

Here, the formula applies "-" twice to a Boolean value. Negating TRUE or FALSE **once** results in the number -1 or 0. Negating TRUE or FALSE **twice** results in the number 1 or 0.

For more information about Excel operators, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/calculation-operators-and-precedence-in-excel-48be406d-4975-4d31-b2b8-7af9e0e2878a.

Comment: thank you. can you help to explain me about "*"? I know it's multiple but as I mentioned, it also used in some formula relating to string of text. So when "*" is used in formula relating to string of text, what's it called?

Comment: @BìnhNguyễn read [here](https://exceljet.net/glossary/wildcard)